# Error: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass installing Ruby 2.0 on Windows 8

Tags: ruby, windows, pik

I installed Ruby 1.9 with the RubyInstaller.  Then installed pik with the gem command.  devkit was also installed.  When trying to install Ruby 2.0 I get this error.

```
C:\var>pik install ruby 2.0.0                          

There was an error.                                    
 Error: private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass  
  in: pik/commands/install_command.rb:24:in `execute'  
  in: pik_runner:33
```

I used `pik` to install versions of Ruby before on `XP`, `Win7` & `Vista`.  The other answers appear related to `JRuby` and `Java`.

Comment: Would you post the `pik/commands/install_command.rb` content around line 24?